# Throw UnauthorizedAccessException from System.IO.Abstractions

Tags: c#, testing, filesystems

I'm using `System.IO.Abstractions` (https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions) to allow me to inject an `IFileSystem` into my class. I've recently added a piece of code to catch an `UnauthorizedAccessException` thrown when the user tries to create a file in a directory which they don't have write access to.

Is there a way the set the access permissions of a directory within `System.IO.Abstractions`?

The following code is as close as I have come (`MockFileSystem` coming from `System.IO.Abstractions`). The `AccessControlSections` description is

> Specifies which sections of a security descriptor to save or load

So it appears that I need to set up a security descriptor of some sort but I can't find any information on that - or if this is even the right approach.

```
var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem();
mockFileSystem.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Test", new DirectorySecurity("C:\\Test", AccessControlSections.None));

// This should throw an UnauthorizedAccessException
mockFileSystem.File.Create("C:\\Test\\File.txt");
```

Comment: It looks like [`Directory.SetAccessControl`](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions/blob/master/System.IO.Abstractions/IDirectory.cs#L71) is a wrapper around the [`Directory.SetAccessControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2) from the BCL, so just follow those MSDN docs?

Comment: This library looks like a lot effort for little gain

Comment: @MichaelRandall it's a massive gain, I can test my whole application without a dependency on any files having to actually exist on a build/test machine. I can also write tests around the file system state because I can inject it into my class.

Comment: @TheGeneral, is making your code testable little gain?

Answer (score 4):

I tried something like this and failed:

```
const string path = @"C:\temp\incoming";
var fileSystem = new MockFileSystem();
fileSystem.AddDirectory(path);
var diFactory = fileSystem.DirectoryInfo;
var directoryInfo = diFactory.FromDirectoryName(path);
var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
var currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(currentUser , FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

I still think this is more or less the way to go, unfortunately it doesn't work :-(

Maybe the user I'm specifying for the AccessRule isn't correct, I've tried with others too but to no avail:

```
var adminUser = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
// -> Doesn't work either..
```

Anyway, in the end I created this dirty workaround to test it, and that works obviously:

```
var mockFileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
mockFileSystem.Setup(x => x.File.Create(It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new Exception());
```

Comment: Please check my answer. As you were interested, it may be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock for `IFileSystem` to setup the method you wanna throw the exception and then you create a `MockFileSystem` to be used only when necessary. You can setup your mock to return the "real" file system when only some methods are invoked. In my case bellow, I wanted to only use `MockFileSystem` when using the `Path`.

You will have to setup your test like this (please read the comments):

```
[Fact]
public async void FailWhenCopyFails()
{
   // Arrange
   var file = Substitute.For<IFile>(); // fake File to throw UnauthorizedAccessException
   file
      .When(x => x.WriteAllBytesAsync(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<byte[]>()))
      .Do(x => { throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(); });

   file.Exists("C:\\Downloads\\" + "eclipse.exe").Returns(true);

   var fileSystem = Substitute.For<IFileSystem>(); // fake file system
   var mockFileSystem = new MockFileSystem(); // "real" file system to be used only when necessary
   fileSystem.File.Returns(file); // pass the File mock which will throw the exception
   fileSystem.Path.Returns(mockFileSystem.Path); // the "real" Path is necessary to make the test pass

   var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
   var httpClient = new HttpClient(new MockHttpMessageHandler(httpResponseMessage));
   var downloader = new DownloadManager(httpClient, fileSystem);

   // Act
   await Assert.ThrowsAsync<UnauthorizedAccessException>(() => downloader.DownloadFile(new Uri(eclipseUrl), downloadFolder));

   // Assert
   downloader.IsSuccess().Should().BeFalse();
}
```

In my case I wanted to verify the download fails if the http client can't create the downloaded file in the downloads folder (it was supposed to fail if it cannot overwrite the C:\Downloads\eclipse.exe already there).